# How to lock or synchronize on a variable when two threads need to update it?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a variable (seqJ) which needs to be updated twice by a thread.

There are two actions which a thread does on this variable, namely:

1. IncrementAndGet(seqJ)
2. Update(seqJ)

Both the methods are executed in the exact order mentioned here.

The second thread should be able to call IncrementAndGet after the update method has been called.

I tried using synchronized(lock) inside these methods, but I am reasoning that once the thread releases the lock in one of the methods, then the other thread can access seqJ via the other method which will give me spurious results.

How to resolve this issue?

```
MainClass{
public int incrementSeqJ () {
    return seqJ.incrementAndGet();
}

public int getSeqJ() {
    return seqJ.get();
}

public void updateSeqJ(int seqJ) {
    if (this.seqJ.get() < seqJ)
        this.seqJ.set(seqJ);
}
}
```

The thread where I am using these methods:

```
public void run() {
    try {

        //socks.setSoTimeout(500);
        totalOrder = gma.totalOrder;

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socks.getInputStream());   //Get reading stream
        ObjectOutputStream sendSSN = new ObjectOutputStream(socks.getOutputStream());

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 2) {
            recObj = ois.readObject();
            //Determine the type of message object received and do actions according to toString values. Use Switch cases.
            switch (Integer.parseInt(recObj.toString())) {

                //Receive MessageObject and send SuggestedSequenceNumber object to sending AVD
                case 1: {
                    MessageObject mo = (MessageObject) recObj;
                    updateUI = mo;

                    int seqJ;
                    /*if(mo.processNum == Integer.parseInt(gma.portStr))
                        seqJ = gma.getSeqJ();
                    else*/
                        seqJ = gma.incrementSeqJ();

                    mo.status = false;
                    mo.sSN = seqJ;
                    mo.sSNProcNum = Integer.parseInt(gma.portStr);

                    Log.d(ReceiverTask.class.getSimpleName(), "Case 1 Adding");
                    totalOrder.addQ(mo);

                    Object msg = new SuggestedSequenceNumber(mo.mID, seqJ, mo.processNum, mo.sSNProcNum);
                    sendSSN.writeObject(msg);

                    break;
                }

                case 3: {
                    FinalMessage fm = (FinalMessage) recObj;

                    MessageObject mo = totalOrder.findInQ(fm.mID, fm.processNum);

                    if (mo == null)
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    else {
                        mo.sSN = fm.sSN;
                        mo.sSNProcNum = fm.sSNProcNum;
                        mo.status = true;
                    }

                    gma.updateSeqJ(fm.sSN);

                    Log.d(ReceiverTask.class.getSimpleName(), "Case 2 Adding");
                    totalOrder.addQ(mo);

                    totalOrder.makeDeliverable(gma.getContentResolver());

                    gma.runOnUiThread(
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    publishProgress(gma, ReceiverTask.this.updateUI);
                                }
                            });

                    ois.close();
                    sendSSN.close();
                    socks.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){ Log.d(ReceiverTask.class.getSimpleName(), "Socket Timed Out"); }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){ Log.d(ReceiverTask.class.getSimpleName(), "MessageObject not found"); }
    catch(IOException e){ Log.d(ReceiverTask.class.getSimpleName(), e.toString()); }
}
```

}

Suppose Thread1 is in incrementSeqJ method: It increments the value and stores it back in SeqJ. Now in my second part of code it is mandatory that thread2 accesses incrementSeqJ method only after thread1 has called the updateSeqJ method.

Comment: Maybe [``AtomicInteger``](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) will solve your problem?

Comment: Please add your code, the "error" in your last paragraph is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking: if your logic dictates that those two methods must be called in sequence - why do you have two methods in your public interface?

You could provide just ONE method to your client code. That method fetches the look, then it calls these other two (internal, possibly private) methods; and releases the lock.

If you think that these two methods "belong" together, then you should not provide and interface that makes it possible to call them separately.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that thread1 has finished updating seqJ before thread2 begins, you can use a CountDownLatch with a count of 1:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

In thread2 before calling the increment function, have:

```
latch.await();
```

And in thread1, after it calls the update function, have:

```
latch.countDown();
```

await() is a blocking function and it waits for the CountDownLatch to count down to 0. In this case, the CountDownLatch only has a count of 1 so once countDown() is called once, it will count down the latch from 1 to 0 and await() will return.

Make sure both threads are both referring to the same instance of the CountDownLatch.

Comment: Suppose Thread1 is in incrementSeqJ method: It increments the value and stores it back in SeqJ. Now in my second part of code it is mandatory that thread2 accesses incrementSeqJ method only when thread1 has called the updateSeqJ method. 

Now will this code work?

Comment: You could use a CountDownLatch. Count down the latch when thread1 has finished executing updateSeqJ and have thread2 waiting for the latch to countdown before it calls incrementSeqJ. See online for examples of Java's CountDownLatch.

Comment: See my updated answer with an example of how to use CountDownLatch to resolve your problem.

Comment: ohk I will try this :)